# Facebook Sharing dialog inside Iframe does not appear when using in-app browser on Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, iframe, inappbrowser

The Javascript SDK sharing dialog (FB.ui) does not appear when used inside an iframe in IOS in-app browser. I've setup a test page for you to see: http://dynamic.hs.fi/2016/arkkutest/

Do the following.

1. Share this link on your Facebook feed with browser: http://dynamic.hs.fi/2016/arkkutest/
2. Click on the link on your browser.
3. Click on the "Share this page on Facebook" -button when the page opens. Share the link again on your feed
4. Switch to Ios app. Click on the link you just shared.
5. Click on the "Share this page on Facebook" -button. And: Nothing happens.

Facebook says this is by design (bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1666486606949456/) So I'm looking for a workaround for the bug. Any ideas?